# Is relation following given characteristic already in 2NF, 3NF and BCNF?

Tags: database-theory, databases

The definitions of 2NF, 3NF and BCNF goes like this:

> **2 Normal Form (NF) definition**
>    A relation is in second normal form if and only if it is in first normal form and all the non-key attributes are fully functionally dependent on the candidate key.
>
> **3 NF - definition**
>     A relation schema $R$ is in third normal form (3NF) if, whenever a nontrivial functional dependency $α→β$ holds in $R$, either
>
> 1. $α$ is a superkey of $R$, or
> 2. $β$ is a prime attribute of $R$.
>
> **BCNF (Boyce–Codd normal form) - definition**
>   A relation schema $R$ is in BCNF, if whenever a nontrivial functional dependency $α→β$ holds in $R$, $α$ is a superkey in $R$.

Based upon these decision, I want to know if the relation having below characteristic is already in some normal form.

**All candidate keys are of single attributes:** this one is definitely in 2NF as there cannot be any partial dependency, but full functional dependency on CK. I am more confused about 3NF and BCNF. I feel its not in 3NF and BCNF since there can exist $\alpha \rightarrow \beta$, such that both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are non key, violating 3NF and BCNF definitions.

Am I right with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a relation schema `R(A, B, C)`, with the functional dependencies:

```
A → B
B → C
```

In this schema there is only one candidate key (`A`), and it has a unique attribute. But the schema is not in BCNF, since `B` is not a superkey, neither in 3NF, since `C` is not a prime attribute.

So your intuition is correct.